# TableView won't show data at all

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Trying to crate a simple tableView that show data but it's not working. I checked and it's not even get into func tableView .. Any ideas what can be the problem?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate , UITableViewDataSource , UITextFieldDelegate {    

    let messageArray = ["First message ", "sec message " , "Third message"]

    @IBOutlet weak var customTableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        customTableView.delegate = self
        customTableView.dataSource = self

        customTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "customCell" , bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "tableCell")
        configureTableView()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableCell"
            , for: indexPath)as! custom

        cell.label0.text = messageArray[0]

        cell.label1.text = messageArray[1]
        cell.label2.text = messageArray[2]
        cell.label3.text = "d"
        customTableView.reloadData()
        return cell
    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }
    func configureTableView() {

        customTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        customTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 120.0


    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that you don't understand how table views work. `cellForRowAt` is called for each item in the data source array, actually the number of times returned in `numberOfRows`, in this case three times. You can access one item for the given index path (`messageArray[indexPath.row]`) and assign the value(s) to the UI element(s). **Never** call `reloadData()` inside  `cellForRowAt`. You might run into an infinite loop

Comment: @vadian thanks for the explanation! but still after deleting it not working.. any ideas?

Comment: Have you set the tableview's delegate correctly?

Comment: @Abizern Sorry i'm a begginer , what do you mean bu that? how can i check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try deleting the `reload data` from cellForRowAt and implementing

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Comment: I tried that , didn't work .. still won't show any data

Answer (score 0):

Register cell before set delegate and data source.

Remove customTableView.reloadData() in `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`

Comment: @Sh_Khan Thank you! I did not know that.

Comment: I tried that , didn't work .. still won't show any data

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a recursive reload becuase you have this in `cellForRowAt`

```
customTableView.reloadData()
```

so comment it and try

Comment: I tried that , didn't work .. still won't show any data

Comment: github the demo quickly and share the link if you want a solution

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove this line: customTableView.reloadData() from datasource method cellForRowAt.

You are basically asking the tableview to reload all of it's data while it is getting the first row from the datasource method. So it's an endless loop. It never gets to show any data.

Comment: I tried that , didn't work .. still won't show any data